# SAS versioning of two tables using data step

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and I'm at a dead end.
I need to get the final table. C with a full set of attributes, and the" intersection " of versioning, i.e. as soon as a version change has occurred in one of the Tariffs or Abonents tables, the version in C should also change. If the version was changed simultaneously, in both tables, then in C the version should be changed once.

```
Tarifs
abon_id tariff_plan type from_date to_date
1 1 1 01OCT2005 01JAN2040
2 1 2 05NOV2005 01DEC2006
2 2 2 02DEC2006 01DEC2007
2 2 1 02DEC2007 01JAN2040
3 0 0 07NOV1917 11JUN1991
3 1 1 12JUN1991 01JAN2040
4 1 1 12JUN1991 01JAN2040

Abonents
abon_id name sex from_date
1 Igor M 01OCT2005 01JAN2040
2 Vasya M 05NOV2005 01AUG2006
2 Lena F 02AUG2006 02SEP2007
2 Yulia F 03SEP2007 01JAN2040
3 USSR Country 07NOV1917 11JUN1991
3 Russia Country 12JUN1991 01JAN2040
4 Petya M 12AUG1991 01JAN2040
```

Resulting table should be:

```
C:
abon_id tariff_plan type name sex fd td
1 1 1 Igor М 01oct2005 01jan2040
2 1 2 Vasya М 05nov2005 01aug2006
2 1 2 Lena F 02aug2006 01dec2006
2 2 2 Lena F 02dec2006 02sep2007
2 2 2 Julia F 03sep2007 01dec2007
2 2 1 Julia F 02dec2007 01jan2040
3 0 0 USSR Country 07nov1917 11jun1991
3 1 1 Russia Country 12jun1991 01jan2040
4 1 1 . . 12jun1991 11aug1991
4 1 1 Petya M 12aug1991 01jan2040
```

So far I have something like:

```
data out;
    retain fd1 fd2 td1 td2;
    format fd1 fd2 td1 td2 ddmmyy10.;
    merge Tarifs(in=x) Abonents(in=y);
    by abon_id fd;

    fd1 = 0; fd2 = 0; td1 = 0; td2 = 0;

    if x then do;
        fd1 = fd;
        td1 = td;
    end;
    if y then do;
        fd2 = fd;
        td2 = td;
    end;

    if fd1 <= fd2 then do;
        fd = fd1;
        if fd2 < td1 and f2 < td2 then td = fd2;
        else if td1 < td2 then td = td1;
        else td = td2;
    end;
    else do;
        fd = fd2;
        if fd1 < td1 and fd1 < td2 then td = fd1;
        else if td1 < td2 then td = td1;
        else td = td2;
    end;

run;
```

But I think I'm doing something wrong. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL union to combine the the overlaps with the tarifs pre-abonent

```
data tarifs;
input
abon_id tariff_plan type from_date: date9. to_date date9.;
format _numeric_ 4. from_date to_date date9.;
datalines;
1 1 1 01OCT2005 01JAN2040
2 1 2 05NOV2005 01DEC2006
2 2 2 02DEC2006 01DEC2007
2 2 1 02DEC2007 01JAN2040
3 0 0 07NOV1917 11JUN1991
3 1 1 12JUN1991 01JAN2040
4 1 1 12JUN1991 01JAN2040

data abonents;
length abon_id 8 name $10 sex $10;
input
abon_id name sex from_date: date9. to_date date9.;
format from_date to_date date9.;
datalines;
1 Igor M 01OCT2005 01JAN2040
2 Vasya M 05NOV2005 01AUG2006
2 Lena F 02AUG2006 02SEP2007
2 Julia F 03SEP2007 01JAN2040
3 USSR Country 07NOV1917 11JUN1991
3 Russia Country 12JUN1991 01JAN2040
4 Petya M 12AUG1991 01JAN2040
;

proc sql;
  create table want as
(
  select 
    A.abon_id, A.tariff_plan, A.type
  , B.name, B.sex
  , case
      when A.from_date < B.from_date then B.from_date else A.from_date
    end as fd format=date9.
  , case
      when A.to_date > B.to_date then B.to_date else A.to_date
    end as td format=date9.
  from tarifs A
  left join abonents B
    on A.abon_id = B.abon_id
  where 
    B.from_date between A.from_date and A.to_date
    or
    B.to_date between A.from_date and A.to_date
)
  union
(
  select 
    A.abon_id, A.tariff_plan, A.type
  , '  ' as name , ' ' as sex
  , A.from_date as fd
  , min(B.from_date)-1 as td
  from tarifs A
  left join abonents B
    on A.abon_id = B.abon_id
  group by
    B.abon_id
  having 
    A.from_date < min(B.from_date)
)
  ;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and responding! Yes, you're right. But I wrote 'using data step' in the topic for a reason. I need to solve it using this(

Comment: Moreover, need to do it with only one data statement. And not using macros too.

Answer (score 0):

A simple merge can not accomplish the task because you need to cross join on abon_id.

A cross join can be accomplished in DATA Step by multidata hashing the abonents, linear traversing the tariffs with SET and iterating over find/find_next.

Example

```
data tarifs;
input
abon_id tariff_plan type from_date: date9. to_date date9.;
format _numeric_ 4. from_date to_date date9.;
datalines;
1 1 1 01OCT2005 01JAN2040
2 1 2 05NOV2005 01DEC2006
2 2 2 02DEC2006 01DEC2007
2 2 1 02DEC2007 01JAN2040
3 0 0 07NOV1917 11JUN1991
3 1 1 12JUN1991 01JAN2040
4 1 1 12JUN1991 01JAN2040
5 1 1 06JAN2021 31DEC2031

data abonents;
length abon_id 8 name $10 sex $10;
input
abon_id name sex from_date: date9. to_date date9.;
format from_date to_date date9.;
datalines;
1 Igor M 01OCT2005 01JAN2040
2 Vasya M 05NOV2005 01AUG2006
2 Lena F 02AUG2006 02SEP2007
2 Julia F 03SEP2007 01JAN2040
3 USSR Country 07NOV1917 11JUN1991
3 Russia Country 12JUN1991 01JAN2040
4 Petya M 12AUG1991 01JAN2040
;

data want(keep=abon_id tariff_plan type name sex tariffed:);
  if 0 then set tarifs abonents;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash abon (dataset:'abonents', multidata:'y');
    abon.defineKey('abon_id');
    abon.defineData('name', 'sex', 'from_date', 'to_date');
    abon.defineDone();
  end;

  set tarifs (rename=(from_date=fd to_date=td));

  min_from = 1e9;
  if abon.find() = 0 then do until (abon.find_next() ne 0);

    if fd <= from_date <= td then tariffed_fd = from_date;
    else
    if from_date <= fd <= to_date then tariffed_fd = fd;

    if fd <= to_date   <= td then tariffed_td = to_date;
    else
    if from_date <= td <= to_date then tariffed_td = td;   

    if nmiss(of tariffed:) = 0 then output;

    if from_date < min_from then min_from = from_date;

    call missing (of tariffed:);
  end;

  if fd < min_from then do;
    tariffed_fd = fd;
    tariffed_td = from_date - 1;
    call missing (name, sex);
    output;
  end;

  format min_from tariffed: date9.;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! I think now there is something for me to think about.